# Setting the span attribute in multi-column xslfo using XEP processor?

Tags: xml, xslt, pdf, xsl-fo

I am now developing a xslfo stylesheet that sets the content to 2-column display, using the RenderX XEP processor. However, I still want to leave the tables as 1-column display, since they are much wider. I found this article extremely helpful:

http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/MultiColumns.html (Navigate down to "Page column spans“ section)

Indeed, since I am using XEP processor, it will not allow me to put an @span="all" attribute at the outer fo:block that containing my table element, since that fo:block is not a direct child of an  fo:flow. So, using the suggested solution in that article, I changed my containing fo:block to fo:wrapper, and now the fo looks like this:

```
 <fo:wrapper font-size="80%" id="table_1ECAD9B3F5FC44A68240330AEFC1C2E2" space-after.optimum="1em" span="all">
  <fo:table border-bottom-color="black" border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1pt" border-left-color="black" border-left-style="solid" border-left-width="1pt" border-right-color="black" border-right-style="solid" border-right-width="1pt" border-top-color="black" border-top-style="solid" border-top-width="1pt" id="" space-after.optimum="5pt" space-before.optimum="5pt" table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
 ....
  </fo:table>
 </fo:wrapper>
```

There is no warning message now in the generation process, seems like it does accept the @span="all" for the fo:wrapper. However, in the resulting pdf, the table is still split into two-columns as before. The article is referring to Docbook xslfo, while I am using a custom xslfo that comes with XMetal.

Wonder if any experts have similar experience (using XEP, setting the @span in a mutil-column environment) to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround that you refer to means that the `<fo:block span="all">` block is kept as it is, and that all its `<fo:block>` ancestors are replaced with `<fo:wrapper>`.

A structure like this one,

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
  <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
     <fo:block>
        <fo:block>
           <fo:block span="all">
             <fo:table>
              ...
```

needs to be replaced with this:

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
  <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
     <fo:wrapper>
        <fo:wrapper>
           <fo:block span="all">
             <fo:table>
              ...
```

Comment: could you look at my follow-up question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710903/put-a-spanning-table-in-its-own-page-sequence

Answer (score 1):

The "[span](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#span)" attribute only [applies](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#prapply) to fo:block and fo:block-container, and only if they are direct children of fo:flow. So, your fo:wrapper needs to become an fo:block.

Comment: If I turn that fo:wrapper into fo:block, I still can not use @span on it, since it is not a direct child of a fo:flow. Can you suggest a way solving this?